# What is the meaning of 怼回去?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I came across a comment:

> 巴西柔术被误以为女子防身术, 怎么怼回去

What is the meaning of 怎么怼回去?

Comment: 怼 is not a common character. maybe more context would help to understand.

Comment: 怼 is the misusage of 㨃 in internet circle of China, like @dan said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

怼回去: Someone said something you do not agree, then you give your opinion  (usually opposite to his/hers) to show your disagreement.

Answer (score 6):

怼 is fairly new internet slang.

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%80%BC) defines it as:

> 怼
>
> duǐ
>
> (Internet slang) to attack verbally / to publicly criticize / to call out

notice: it is read in the third tone here and basically means *to lay into*.

With the rise of popularity of 怼, many new words came out and have started popping up everywhere.

Not to get off topic too much, but another common new word is 怒怼.

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=nudui):

> 怒怼
>
> nùduǐ
>
> (Internet slang) to chastise / to angrily denounce

This hopefully gives a better overall view of what 怼 actually means.

Another new word, that would answer your question more clearly, that has come out is 回怼:

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%9B%9E%E6%80%BC)

> 回怼
>
> huíduǐ
>
> to retaliate verbally / to hit back (at critics)

So back to your question:

> 怎么怼回去?

Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu has been attacked and now they’re asking how to *retaliate* or how to *hit back at* their attackers.

Comment: duǐ回去 is actually the dialect expression from northeast China. We never know the written version of duǐ. It sounds very folksy to me.

Comment: @dan It's everywhere now. You can look up 怼, 怒怼, 回怼, 怼回去 it's all over the internet.

Comment: @dan Three days ago 凤凰网 had the headline: 爱怼中国的美国四星上将被换了

Answer (score 2):

duǐ,  in fact, should be written as 㨃. It's originated from the northeast dialect. It's been written as 怼 on internet now for some reason. I guess it might be because we don't know the correct writting originally and just find one from any Pinyin Input.

The idea of 㨃 is that: to push, to knock against, and figuratively to talk against, or fight back, etc.

Answer (score -1):

怼= 懟 as in 怨懟 (resent; resentment )

> https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%80%BC/4505099
>
> 怼是一个汉语字，拼音为duì，基本意思是会意字，说文，心部，从对声。对，相持也，意为互相对峙，底下加“心”，表示心里抵触，对抗。引申为怨恨，**故而怼，怨也**。(therefore 怼 means 'resent')

- '对' in '怼' means '对抗' (to confront)
- '心' in '怼' indicates 'from the heart; emotionally; mentally'
- '怼' means '**resent**'
- '怼**回去**' seems to mean  '**respond** with bitter confrontation'